# tried making a program for finding numbers where the sum of all the factors of the number equals the same number. C#

Tags: c#

I want the program to write out all numbers where the sum of the factors equal the number. for example 6, 6 is evenly dividable by 3, 2 and 1. 3+2+1 = 6. but the program just prints out 3 and nothing more. I dont understand why it doesnt work.

```
long b = 0;
List<long> evenDeviders = new List<long>();


for (long n = 1; n < 1000000; n++)
{
    for (long j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
    
        if ( n % j == 0 )
        {
            evenDeviders.Add(j);
        }

    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < evenDeviders.Count; i++)
    {
        b += evenDeviders[i];
    }
    
    if ( b == n )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, what you are looking for are called _Perfect Numbers_ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number

Comment: This looks like a chance to learn to use the debugger. Are the values created as the program runs what you expect them to be?

Comment: @Flydog57 yes i know they are called perfect numbers. maybe should have added that in the question but i assumed it would be better to explain directly what i was after as some might not know what perfect number means. anyways thanks regardless for answering

Comment: Look carefully whether the state of your variables at the start of the outer loop always corresponds to what you intend it to be. Also, using `List` in this case is quite redundant, you could just compute the sum right away. Also think about what you could improve algorithmically about the inner loop so that it runs in O(sqrt(n)) rather than O(n).

Comment: @stuartd as i am a newbie to coding i am unaware of what that is or how to do that.. please fill me in

Comment: Thanks you guys helped! realized that i never reset the value for b lol. i fixed it by just defining b as 0 inside the outer loop.